# Is there any law or by-law stopping me from planting my own trees?

Tags: united-kingdom, trees

Recently on my road, two trees have been removed by local government that were on a small strip of public land in front of houses on the street, and when asked it seems that I can **request** to have a new tree planted where the old ones were (which sounds like a lot of bureaucracy.) I am hence asking, is there anything stopping me from planting a tree that *I* buy and planting it where the old ones were?

Comment: Were the trees on public ground or your own / someone else's private property?

Comment: @TomRevell I have just added some more description

Comment: Municipalities often have lists of approved tree species--non-invasive, native, etc.